# Dynamically hiding a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input text box, I want to change its class dynamically by using Javascript. I also have to make it hidden. How can I do it?

```
<input id="mybutton" iconClass="iconclassbutton" class="classTochange" label="done" />
```

Comment: A quick heads up here, the HTML you're using there isn't valid. Adding your own attributes is **not recommended**, and you should be using the `title` attribute or the `label` *element* instead of the `label` *attribute*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
button.style.visibility = hidden;
button.className = newClass;
```

You don't have a type attribute on the input element though, is that on purpose?

Comment: somethimes developers avoid writing the type to default the <input to a text field an gain 14bytes but in this case he got a button... *curious*

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#mybutton").hide()
$("#mybutton").toggleClass("classTochange","newclass")
```

If not mistaken - do check the jQuery documentation to confirm it

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify under what circumstances would you want to change the class and then hide the text box? I am assuming 'class' here is stylesheet class.
Anyway, if you don't want to use jQuery, the javascript could be modified like this:

```
function toggleButton(){
    var button=document.getElementById('mybutton');
    if(button.className=="classTochange"){
        button.className="newClass";
        button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
        button.className="classTochange";
        button.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```